# yet another unknown terminal type

Tags: macos, xterm, terminfo

From Ubuntu, I open `gnome-terminal`, and ssh to a `OS X`.

`OS X` version is:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F34
```

I have for example the file `xterm-256color`:

```
$ ls /usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color
```

But I can't do a simple `clear`:

```
$ TERM='xterm-256color' clear
'xterm-256color': unknown terminal type.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shell may set `TERMINFO` to some other location than `/usr/share/terminfo`, and confuse the ncurses library. The ncurses library has a compiled-in fallback value for `TERMINFO`, which can be overridden by setting the environment variable.

You may also have (from packages or the like, e.g., homebrew) a copy of `clear` in your path before `/usr/bin/clear` which points to an incomplete terminal database.

For the latter, "which clear" would show where that is the case.  If you also have `infocmp`, the same information is available, e.g., in the first line of its output.

It is also possible to have a corrupted terminal database (why, I cannot say), and because the ncurses library makes some runtime checks on each entry, it could refuse to load those without apparent cause.

Comment: `TERMINFO` was not set. `TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo TERM=xterm clear` works. Thanks!

Comment: `TERM=xterm /usr/bin/clear` also works. I didn't noticed that I was running  `/Users/froger/miniconda/bin/clear`, comming from 
https://binstar.org/asmeurer/ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me at OSX 10.10.3. I'm pretty sure it also worked on 10.9.x. I would say that something is wrong with that particular machine, but it is just a wild guess. Try xterm-color or plain xterm. Also, '' are not necessary there.